# Left outer join is null- additional conditions

Tags: oracle, left-join, outer-join, isnull

I'm trying to find all entries in table a, where there is no matching entry in table b for one specific column (order). I'm using the following:

```
SELECT *
       FROM a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN b
       ON a.id = b.id
       WHERE b.order IS NULL
       AND a.result>10
```

However, the last condition for result doesn't seems to work. It simply lists all the entries from table a, regardless whether result is more than 10 or not.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your query be as below?

SELECT * FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id WHERE **b.id** IS NULL AND a.result>10

Comment: That won't make much of a difference. The issue is that with the left outer join I can't filter anything from table a on the left side, i.e. the table that matches its rows with the rows of table b, where value IS NULL